# Integrating inline tinymce editor in a component for a gutenberg block

Tags: tinymce, block-editor

I'm new to stack exchange. I hope my question is not to long.

I want to integrate an inline tinymce editor in a component and use it in a gutenberg block. But my editors ui conflicts with gutenberg. (first screenshot)

The editor-element is inside a backbone view. I can’t use the RichText editor component in my case.

#### Background:

I‘m developing a plugin to insert leaflet maps into a post https://github.com/jhotadhari/geo-masala

The Plugin has a Gutenberg block to insert and control a map and its appearance/popups/controls/markers… .

Map-Features (Markers/Lines/Polygons) are saved as a custom-post-type: geom_feature. Each geom_feature has meta for geoJSON, appearance...
The custom-post-type is registered without ui. All crud actions for geom_feature(s) are done within a gutenberg block (eg. drawing a marker creates a new geom_feature)

Inside the block, one component renders a leaflet map into a ref element. The component uses backbone to fetch the geom_feature(s) as a collection.
When a Map-Feature (Leaflet.layer) is clicked, a toolbar opens with different editing options. The popup content can be edited within a popup (using a backform form with a custom wysiwyg field). The popup content is the post-content of the geom_feature.

The custom wysiwyg field uses a tinymce inline editor. All (eg updating new content to database) works fine, but the ui of that editor breaks. The editor toolbar and widgets are not in place.

I can init the editor with a fixed_toolbar_container. Like this:

```
initMceEditor: function(){
    let self = this;

    if ( this.mceEditor )
        return this;

    // setup editor element
    this.getMceElement().attr( 'id', this.cid );
    // setup toolbar element
    this.setupToolbar();

    let settings = _.extend( {}, wp.editor.getDefaultSettings().tinymce, {
        selector: this.cid,
        inline: true,
        toolbar1: [
            'formatselect fontsizeselect bold italic underline',
            'bullist numlist',
            'alignleft aligncenter alignright',
            'link pastetext',
        ].join(' | '),
        toolbar: true,
        fixed_toolbar_container: '#geom-inline-editor-toolbar-' + this.cid,
        content_css: geomData.pluginDirUrl + '/css/tinymce_content.min.css',
        setup: function (editor) {
            // editor events
            // ... some lines skipped
        },
    });

    // init mceEditor
    this.mceEditor = tinymce.createEditor( this.cid, settings );

    // render mceEditor
    this.mceEditor.render();

    return this;
},
```

This works but the appearance of the toolbar is not as expected. And mce panels and tooltips are displayed at the end of the document. See the first screenshot.

[image]

I can apply some style to fix this:

```
.geom-toolbar {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    .geom-inline-editor-toolbar {
        width: 100%;
        .mce-flow-layout-item {
            float: left;
        }
        .mce-widget.mce-btn {
            float: left;
            button {
                padding: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

// stupid fix, dont do that!
.mce-widget.mce-tooltip[role="presentation"] {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.mce-container.mce-panel.mce-floatpanel {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

The Editor looks like this then:

[image]

That’s not a good solution at all. And it will conflict somewhere.

### Back to the Question

Does someone knows a way, to include an inline tinymce editor that doesn’t conflict with gutenberg?

Do I have to load some default styles for my tinymce editor that are not loaded by gutenberg? And how to limit their scope to my components
Or can advise me way.

I don't search for a solution that uses gutenbergs RichText component.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Gutenbergs FreeformEdit Component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/3d009d29bd6a23a906b07907311e6a995246fb02/core-blocks/freeform) (used for the classic editor block) demonstrates the way how to integrate a tinyMce editor.

Recoded my custom Backform [WysiwygControl](https://github.com/jhotadhari/geo-masala/blob/7fae754ceff9e603cdf0690222dfb2d7c57a2248/src/commonJS/geom_block_map/formControls/WysiwygControl.js) and adopted the tinyMce integration.

```
/**
 * External dependencies
 */
import Backform from 'Backform';

/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { F10, ESCAPE, ALT } = wp.utils.keycodes;

/**
 * Wysiwyg Control
 *
 * The tinyMce integration is mostly copied from the gutenberg/core-blocks/freeform component (classic editor)
 *
 */
const WysiwygControl = Backform.Control.extend({

    defaults: {
        label: '',
        helpMessage: null
    },

    // ./form.js inits the controls with options for layer and model
    initialize( options ) {
        Backform.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.layer = options.layer;
    },

    template: _.template([
        '<label class="<%=Backform.controlLabelClassName%>"><%=label%></label>',
        '<div class="<%=Backform.controlsClassName%>">',
        '  <div class="geom-inline-editor" <%=disabled ? "disabled" : ""%> <%=required ? "required" : ""%> >',
        '    <%= value %>',
        '  </div>',
        '  <% if (helpMessage && helpMessage.length) { %>',
        '    <span class="<%=Backform.helpMessageClassName%>"><%=helpMessage%></span>',
        '  <% } %>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('\n')),

    events: _.extend({}, Backform.Control.prototype.events, {
        'click': 'onClick',
        'dblclick': 'onClick',
    }),

    onClick(e){
        if ( e ) e.preventDefault();
        const { baseURL, suffix } = window.wpEditorL10n.tinymce;

        if ( this.editor ) return this;

        window.tinymce.EditorManager.overrideDefaults( {
            base_url: baseURL,
            suffix,
        } );

        if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
            this.initEditor();
        } else {
            window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', this.initEditor );
        }
    },

    setupToolbar(){
        if ( ! this.$toolbar ){
            // create toolbar element
            this.$toolbar = $('<div>', {
                id: 'geom-inline-editor-toolbar-' + this.cid,
                class: 'geom-inline-editor-toolbar freeform-toolbar',
                ['data-placeholder']: __( 'Classic' ),
            } );
            // append toolbar to container
            this.$el.closest('div[data-type="geom/map"]').find('.geom-toolbar').append(this.$toolbar);
            // animate toolbar
            let autoHeight = this.$toolbar.css('height', 'auto').height();
            this.$toolbar.height(0).animate({height: autoHeight}, 500, () => this.$toolbar.css('height', 'auto') );
            // toolbar events
            this.$toolbar.on('keydown', this.onToolbarKeyDown.bind(this) );
        }
    },

    getEditorElement(){
        return this.$el.find('.geom-inline-editor');
    },

    initEditor() {
        const { settings } = window.wpEditorL10n.tinymce;
        if ( this.editor ) return;
        // setup editor element
        this.getEditorElement().attr( 'id', 'editor-' + this.cid );
        // setup toolbar element
        this.setupToolbar();
        // initialize
        wp.oldEditor.initialize( 'editor-' + this.cid, {
            tinymce: {
            ...settings,
            inline: true,
            content_css: geomData.pluginDirUrl + '/css/geom_block_map_editor_tinymce_content.min.css',
            fixed_toolbar_container: '#geom-inline-editor-toolbar-' + this.cid,
            setup: this.onSetup.bind(this),
        },
        } );
    },

    onSetup( editor ) {
        const self = this;
        const content  = this.getEditorElement().html();
        this.editor = editor;

        editor.addButton( 'kitchensink', {
            tooltip: __( 'More' ),
            icon: 'dashicon dashicons-editor-kitchensink',
            onClick: function() {
                const button = this;
                const active = ! button.active();
                button.active( active );
                editor.dom.toggleClass( self.$toolbar, 'has-advanced-toolbar', active );
            },
        } );

        if ( content ) {
            editor.on( 'loadContent', () => editor.setContent( content ) );
        }

        editor.on( 'init', () => {
            // Create the toolbar by refocussing the editor.
            editor.getBody().blur();
            editor.focus();
        } );

        // // ??? well that doesn't work... will fix that in future
        // editor.on('keydown', ( event ) => {
        //  const { altKey } = event;
        //  // Prevent Mousetrap from kicking in: TinyMCE already uses its own 'alt+f10' shortcut to focus its toolbar.
        //  // if ( altKey && event.keyCode === F10 ) {
        //  if ( event.keyCode === F10 ) {
        //      event.stopPropagation();
        //  }
        // });

        editor.on( 'blur', (event) => {
            this.setModelVal(event);
            return false;
        } );

        editor.on('KeyUp Change Paste input touchend', ( event ) => {
            // close editor if esc pressed
            if ( event.keyCode === ESCAPE ) {
                this.close(event);
            }
        });

        editor.on('focusout', ( event ) => {
            if ( undefined !== $( event.explicitOriginalTarget ) ){

                if ( $( event.explicitOriginalTarget ).attr('id') ){
                    if ( $( event.explicitOriginalTarget ).attr('id').startsWith('mce') ){
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if ( event.explicitOriginalTarget.tagName === 'BUTTON' ){
                    this.setModelVal(event);
                    this.close(event);
                    $( event.explicitOriginalTarget ).trigger('click');
                    return;
                }
            }
            this.setModelVal(event);
            this.close(event);
        });
    },

    focus() {
        if ( this.editor ) {
            this.editor.focus();
        }
    },

    onToolbarKeyDown( event ) {
        // Prevent WritingFlow from kicking in and allow arrows navigation on the toolbar.
        event.stopPropagation();
        // Prevent Mousetrap from moving focus to the top toolbar when pressing 'alt+f10' on this block toolbar.
        event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },

    close(e){
        if ( e ) e.preventDefault();
        this.removeEditor();
    },

    setModelVal(e){
        if ( e ) e.preventDefault();
        const model = this.model;
        const val = this.editor.getContent();
        const oldVal = model.get( this.field.get( 'name' ) ) || model.get( this.field.get( 'name' ) ).rendered;
        const newVal = this.formatter.toRaw( val ) || this.formatter.toRaw( val ).rendered;
        if ( ! _.isUndefined( newVal ) ) this.model.set( 'content', newVal );
    },

    getValueFromDOM() {
        return this.formatter.toRaw( this.getEditorElement().html(), this.model );
    },

    removeEditor() {
        if ( this.editor ){
            window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', this.initEditor );
            wp.oldEditor.remove( 'editor-' + this.cid );
            this.removeToolbar();
            delete this.editor;
            this.getEditorElement().attr( 'id', null);
        }
    },

    removeToolbar(){
        if ( this.$toolbar ){
            this.$toolbar.animate({height: 0}, 500, () => {
                this.$toolbar.remove();
                delete this.$toolbar;
            });
        }
    },

});

export default WysiwygControl;
```

[New Plugin Version 0.0.7](https://github.com/jhotadhari/geo-masala/tree/7fae754ceff9e603cdf0690222dfb2d7c57a2248)

... well the best way would be to build everything in React. But thats another story

**Update 10 July 2018:** Updated plugin links to version 0.0.6 (compatible with gb 3.2.0 and wp 4.9.7)
**Update 12 July 2018:** Updated plugin links to version 0.0.7 (compatible with gb 3.2.0 and wp 4.9.7)